# Webgl Context return null in Node js command prompt

Tags: node.js, npm, webgl

I am currently working in node js. In node js command prompt, the webgl context return null.Is there any way to support webgl in node js ?

Comment: You need to provide more details than that. How do you try to obtain a context? What OS and node version are you running?

Comment: I am running webgl-context library in js file with compiling in node js command prompt in windows

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use [browser-specific](https://github.com/Jam3/get-canvas-context/blob/master/index.js#L10) module from node. No wonder it doesn't work. You can try for example [`node-webgl`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-webgl).